# Getting error when trying to Rename multiple tables in SPROC in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I've created a DB2 sql script that populates a static table and then does a rename to swap out the live table with the newly updated one.  Its a fairly large SQL script so I'm only including the areas that Im having a an error on.

I'm getting the error: "[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "RENAME" was found following "D_HOLIDAY_LOG_OLD;  ".  Expected tokens may include:  "TRUNCATE".  LINE NUMBER=382.  SQLSTATE=42601".

I suspect, its a syntax issue with the RENAME commands.  If I need to add the whole query, I can.  Thanks in advance

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_SPROC()
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SP_NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_SPROC
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN

COMMIT;
TRUNCATE TABLE TMWIN.NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG immediate;
```

```
DROP TABLE NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_OLD;
RENAME TABLE TMWIN.NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_LIVE TO NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_OLD;
RENAME TABLE TMWIN.NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG TO NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_LIVE;
RENAME TABLE TMWIN.NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_OLD TO NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG;

END@
```

Comment: Consider using a commit after the truncate statement

Comment: Consider having two tables and a VIEW over them. Re-point the view between the two sets of tables.  This will avoid needs a RENAME TABLE which will wait on any running queries. Use TRUNCATE and an INSERT to repopulate the non-live table before the view swap.  Nonetheless the view re-create will need to be dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is frequently asked.

As you are using static SQL in an SQL PL stored procedure, you must follow the documented rules for blocks of [Compound SQL (Compiled)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html) statements.

On of those rules is that static SQL has a restricted set of statements that can appear in such a block of code.

For example, with current versions of Db2-LUW, you cannot use any of the following **statically** (including rename table) :
 `ALTER , CONNECT,CREATE,  DESCRIBE,  DISCONNECT,  DROP, FLUSH EVENT MONITOR, FREE LOCATOR, GRANT,  REFRESH TABLE,  RELEASE (connection only),  RENAME TABLE,  RENAME TABLESPACE,  REVOKE, SET CONNECTION, SET INTEGRITY, SET PASSTHRU, SET SERVER OPTION ,TRANSFER OWNERSHIP`

Other Db2 platforms (Z/OS, i-series) might have different restrictions but the same principle.

To achieve what you need you can use dynamic SQL instead of Static-SQL (as long as you understand the implications).

In other words, instead of writing:

`RENAME TABLE TMWIN.NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_LIVE TO NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_OLD;`

you could instead use:

`execute immediate('RENAME TABLE TMWIN.NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_LIVE TO NSD_HOLIDAY_LOG_OLD' );`

or equivalent.

You can also use two statements, one to [PREPARE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000975.html) and the other to [EXECUTE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000948.html) , whichever suits the design. Refer to the documentation for [execute immediate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000950.html).

The same is true for other statements that your version of Db2 disallows in static compound-SQL (compiled) blocks (for example,  DROP, or CREATE etc.).

Comment: Awesome thank you Mao that seemed to work.  Just a follow up, the SQL state took about 5 minutes to run but the SPROC was taking over 12 minutes, is there something I need to keep an eye on for performance issues?   Thank you again

Comment: @Cypherwolf If the answer resolved your first SQL0104N symptom, it is best to mark the answer correct.  For different issues, such as performance, a separate question is required , as different facts would need to be provided.